# PHP SMTP Mail script not working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm coding a php smtp mail script to send a mail to my users when they lose their password. However it's not working.

The processor always returns:

> Message could not be sent...

I've tried it with Gmail smtp and I'm getting the same results.

Can you help? There are two files, the form, and the processor.

Below are the codes:

form:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name = 'viewport' content = 'width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale = 4.0, user-scalable = yes'>
<link rel = 'stylesheet' href = 'style.css' type = 'text/css'>
<title>Reset Password</title>
</head>
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=db;charset=utf8', 'user', 'pass');
$sql = $db->query('select id from posts order by id desc');
$row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo "<a href = 'browse.php?page=".$row['id']."'>Browse</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href = 'index.php'>Home</a>";
echo "<hr>";
echo '<form name = "forgot-pass" action = "reset-pass-notif.php" method = "post">
<label><em>Input your registered email address</em></label><br>
<input type = "text" name = "email"><br>
<em>Enter Image Text:</em><img src="captcha.php" /><br />
<input name="captcha" type="text" /><br>
<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Send Reset-Password Link">
</form>
<hr>
<a href = "browse.php?page='.$row["id"].'">Browse</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href = "index.php">Home</a>';
?>

</html>
```

processor:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name = 'viewport' content = 'width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale = 4.0, user-scalable = yes'>
<link rel = 'stylesheet' href = 'style.css' type = 'text/css'>
<title>Reset Password Notification</title>
</head>
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=db;charset=utf8', 'user', 'pass');
$sql0 = $db->query('select id from posts order by id desc limit 1');
$row0 = $sql0->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo '<a href = "browse.php?page='.$row0['id'].'">Browse</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href = "index.php">Home</a>';
echo '<hr>';
$email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
$sql = $db->prepare('select * from users where email = :email');
$sql->bindParam(':email', $email);
$sql->execute();
$sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$row = $sql->fetch();
$username = $row['username'];
$user_check = $row['user_hash'];
$subject = 'Reset your Password';
$link = '<a href = "http://example.com/reset-pass-land.php?username='.$row['username'].'&user_check='.$row['user_hash'].'">http://bquotes.xyz/reset-pass-land.php?username='.$row['username'].'&user_check='.$row['user_hash'].'</a>';
$message = 'Reset your password here: '.$link.' If you cannot click on the link, copy it and paste in your browser address bar';
$sql = $db->prepare('select email from users where email = :email');
$sql->bindParam(':email', $email);
$sql->execute();
$sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$row = $sql->fetch();

//require_once ('class.phpmailer.php');
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'mail.domain.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user@domain.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'pass';                           // SMTP password
//$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                  // TCP port to connect to
$mail->setFrom('user@domain.com', 'BQuotes Webmaster');
//$mail->addAddress($email);     // Add a recipient
/*$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg'); */   // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body    = $message;
//$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

/*if(!$mail->send()) {
    //echo '<em>Message could not be sent. Mailer Error:</em> ', "<em>", $mail->ErrorInfo, "</em>";
      echo '<span class = "red"><em>Message could not be sent. You have one or more invalid fields.</em></span>';
} else {
    echo '<span class = "green"><em>Message has been sent. Please check your Spam folders if not in Inbox by 10 minutes.</em></span>';
}*/

if (($email)&&($username)&&!empty($_POST['captcha'])&&($_POST['captcha']==$_SESSION['code'])&&($mail->send())){
echo '<span class = "green"><em>Message has been sent. Please check your Spam folders if not in Inbox by 10 minutes.</em></span>';
}

else {echo '<span class = "red"><em>Message could not be sent. You have one or more invalid fields.</em></span>';
}

echo "<hr>";
echo '<a href = "browse.php?page='.$row0['id'].'">Browse</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href = "index.php">Home</a>';
?>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your conditional statement has many places that may cause the email not to be sent. Have you checked each one separately to ensure it has the expected value?

Comment: I've checked. The only problem seems to be with the $mail->send() but I can't imagine what it is

Comment: you have `$mail->SMTPDebug` set. What does the debug information say? It should tell you what the error is during transmission.

Comment: It doesn't say anything..

Comment: read this page to learn how to get your debug output: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/SMTP-Debugging

Answer (score 1):

The correct setting for PHPMailer:

```html
<?php

   $mail = new PHPMailer;
   $mail->IsSMTP();
   $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
   $mail->Username = "user@domain.com";
   $mail->Password = "xxxx";
   $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";  
   $mail->Host = "smtp.domain.com";
   $mail->Port = "465";
   $mail->setFrom('from@domain.com', 'John Doe');
   $mail->addReplyTo('from@domain.com', 'John Doe');
   $mail->AddAddress("mailto@otherdomain.com", "Jane Smith");
   $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
   $mail->IsHTML(true);
   $mail->Subject = 'Bla bla or from DB';
   $mail->Body    = 'Here come the content...';
   if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    exit;
   }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use this code .make sure you have given permission in Mail account from you want to send mail.

**My Account->Sign-in & security->Allow less secure apps: OFF**

```
        $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
        $mail->SMTPDebug = false;                                 
        $mail->isSMTP();                                      
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.live.com';                         
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               
        $mail->Username = 'mail@gmail.com';                 
        $mail->Password = 'Password';                           
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            
        $mail->Port = 587;                                    
        $mail->setFrom($details['from'], $details['from']);
        if(is_array($details['to'])){
            foreach ($details['to'] as $key => $value) {
                $mail->addAddress($value['email'], $value['name']);
            }
        }else{
            $mail->addAddress($details['to'], isset($details['name'])?:$details['to']);
        }

        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject =$details['subject'];
        $mail->Body    =$details['body'];
        $mail->send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this on localhost? Try Putting off your antivirus for some time. Antivirus tends to block email sending from localhost at times